# How to run hprof on mac

Tags: java, macos, hprof

I was trying to use hprof on mac, however, when I run the following command

`java -agentlib:hprof=help`

I get the following:-

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not find agent library hprof on the library path, with error: dlopen(libhprof.dylib, 1): image not found
```

Comment: I actually solved it by reverting back to an older version of jdk!